# how to identify the long class names using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I was trying to identify the name of a class using the following code but it was throwing error all the time :

```
WebElement startdate= images.findElement(By.className("gt-cur-date-val.start-date-val.ng-pristine.hasDatepicker.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-touched"));
```

here input id is `dp1473431696363` and classname is `gt-cur-date-val start-date-val ng-pristine hasDatepicker ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched`.

Comment: pls add the html code..

Comment: <input id="dp1473426331557" ng-model="tripDetails.startDate" class="gt-cur-date-val start-date-val ng-pristine hasDatepicker ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" jq-datepicker="" required="" type="text">

Comment: @Ranjith's have added the html content as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are using syntax as `cssSelector` while using `By.className()` which is wrong.

You should try using `By.cssSelector()` instead as :-

```
WebElement startdate= images.findElement(By.className("input.gt-cur-date-val.start-date-val[ng-model='tripDetails.startDate']"));
```

**Note** :- `By.className()` doesn't support to locate an element with compound class.

Comment: Thanks alot @Saurabh Gaur :)

Comment: Is there any way to get it by using classname only